# What is the different between PAC and MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, pac

I have doubt about this two pattern, like MVC and PAC, which is more powerful for a web Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your web application. For most, common, scenarios I would say MVC works better, but in some cases PAC might be a better fit. What are you requirements?